# HATEOAS JAX-RS Link-Headers

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, hateoas

I am currently trying to build a RESTful API using raw JAX-RS. I have learned that when building REST APIs, there is the principle called HATEOAS(Hypermedia as the engine of application state). In my class we used Link Headers to tell the client, how to further progress the application. I have managed to implement all basic functionality and can access the server after deploying the application to a tomcat server.
My question now is, how do I add a header-link that contains a wildcard for the user to fill in, for example an id?

So far I have tried

```
@Path("/resources")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listAllResources() 
{
     List<TestResource> resources = ...
     // get stuff from database
     return Response.ok(resources)
                    .link(UriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path("{id}").build(), "edit")
                    .build;
}
```

After I try to access the above defined path, I get an error message that the template variable id is undefined.
I can't find any helpful resource that shows me how to create a link header that looks like:

```
link: <http://example.com/api/resources/{id}>; rel: "edit"
```

I hope my question was clear enough since this is my first question on stackoverflow :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that links like in my example `http://example.com/api/resources/{id}` aren't possible by JAX-RS because the UriBuilder tries to resolve any URL part that's surrounded by curly braces. So just use like `http://example.com/api/resources/:id`, if you want to give an Uri Template. Unfortunately the client then has to do something like a String.replace() to actually "create" a valid URI.